# Error in Connect Salesforce using Excel Connector

Tags: community, appexchange, excel, salesforceexcelconnector

I have a requirement to connect to salesforce from excel by Salesforce connector add-ins. After installing and configuring the whole as mentioned here

https://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/wiki/Install

I am getting below error.

> Error Generated by request::mismatched tag at byte index 6670
>   Exception Code1 Could not establish connection to API service.

Note: I didn't change Macro setting and changed the Server URL to that of sandbox- test.salesforce.

Please let me know if I am doing mistakes here.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution from here. Please change the URL as mentioned here.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008sivIAA